# Query getting failed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a session and echo if the login,password and status is 1 ,So if its correct then its session is inserted and if wrong then echo a message but the query is being failed,Would appreciate for any help !

```
if(isset($submit))
    {

        $query=mysql_query("select * from mst_user where login='$loginid' and pass='$pass' AND status IS 1");
        $result_check_credentials = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result_check_credentials){//If the QUery Failed 
            echo 'Query Failed ';
        }

        if (@mysql_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1)
            {

                $_SESSION[login]=$loginid;
                echo " working";
            }
        else
            {
                echo 'sads';
            }
    }
if (isset($_SESSION[login]))
    {
        echo 'welcome'
            }
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Well, the query is wide open to SQL injection, so it could be failing to any reason.  Use `mysql_error()` to determine why it's failing.  (Also, look into using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, since `mysql_*` is long since deprecated anyway.)

Comment: Thanks Mr.David,Where shall i put mysql_error()?

Comment: Probably inside the "query failed" conditional block, since that's where there would be an error to report.

Comment: If `$result_check_credentials` is `false` then there was an error.  You have to debug to determine what that error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status IS 1` should be `status = 1`. `IS` can only be used as part of `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, it's not a general equality operator.

Another problem is this:

```
$result_check_credentials = mysql_query($query);
```

The argument to `mysql_query()` must be a string, but `$query` is the result of calling `mysql_query()`, so you don't need to call it again. Change the previous line to:

```
$query = "select * from mst_user where login='$loginid' and pass='$pass' AND status = 1";
```

Other issues:

- When the query fails, you should exit the code, not fall through to the code that calls `mysql_num_rows()`.
- `$_SESSION[login]` should be `$_SESSION['login']`.

Comment: No database selected

Comment: After you call `mysql_connect()` you need to call `mysql_select_db()` to set the default database for queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are learning still, but please just switch over to PDO or even mysqli.  Plenty of tutorials out there.

However to answer your question is $query defined?

ex:
$query = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

Comment: Yes sir ,It is there

Answer (score 0):

What on Earth are you doing here?:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from mst_user where login='$loginid' and pass='$pass' AND status IS 1");
$result_check_credentials = mysql_query($query);
```

You're executing the query, and then trying to re-execute the *results* of the query?

Just execute the query once.  The returned value will be the result of that query.  Which in this case would be zero or more records from the `mst_user` table.  (Or `false` if the query fails.)

Comment: @user3184290: There appear to be multiple things wrong with your code, pointed out by a small variety of answers posted here.  Additionally, there are many further things which *could* be wrong with your code, not present in the code posted in the question.  Stack Overflow can't debug your code for you.  You should really start with some introductory tutorials on PHP/MySQL.  Just repeating "it doesn't work" on Stack Overflow over and over isn't going to get you anywhere.